# Is there a way to change settings (e.g. font-smoothing) on remote desktop sessions that are launched via the web, e.g. a portal system?

Tags: remote-desktop, fonts, juniper

I'm not sure what the proper terminology is for such remote desktop sessions. To remote into my work computer from home, I have to log in to a portal ("Juniper terminal services") using an RSA SecurID token, and click a link that launches the remote desktop session.

Is there a way to configure the settings for such sessions? For example, multiple-monitor support, or more urgently, font-smoothing (a.k.a. ClearType fonts). (Please do comment on alternative solutions to enabling font-smoothing!)

The portal provides a page where I can configure only a limited selection of settings:

[image: Juniper terminal services]

I wondered if there was a way to force these sessions to pick up their settings from the registry or some other place. Having read that many of these settings are configurable client-side, I thought there might be a way to get around the web-link defaults.

Comment: For now I've found a font called [Dino](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Jibz/Dina/index.html) on [this survey of fonts](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30040/Font-Survey-42-of-the-Best-Monospaced-Programming) that looks the same with or without ClearType. I've tried a few others but thought this was the most acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If someone offers an actual answer, I'll unaccept this answer and accept theirs, but for now I've worked around my issues.

Even though font-smoothing seems disabled by *default*, I found I was able to enable ClearType *manually*, though I have to go through the ClearType Text Tuner every time I log in (it's worth it). In Windows 7, go to **Control Panel**, **Display**, **Adjust ClearType text**,  **Turn on ClearType**, and follow the steps.

As for multiple monitors support, I simply shelled out $400 for [a 2560x1440 monitor](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?p_id=10509&seq=1&format=2), and installed [Winsplit Revolution](http://winsplit-revolution.com/) and set up hotkeys for docking windows to each quadrant of the screen. A costly solution, but nice if you can afford it; it's like having four 1280x720 screens on one monitor.

Comment: I do not see "Adjust ClearType text" at all. http://i.stack.imgur.com/2V8Ps.png How did you get to there?

Comment: I was in Windows 7 default Aero theme. I'm not sure where it would be in classic mode.

Comment: @Pacerier click the `Effects` button and then change the `use the following method to smooth edges of screen fonts` dropdown: http://www.techmynd.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/clear-type-fonts.gif

Answer (score 0):

I have never used the Juniper system, but I have some experience with Remote Desktop Web Access (the native solution to what you are describing). In RDWA, you have the option to save the .RDP file to your local machine (right-click -> Save target as) and then you can edit the .RDP file locally to your wish (some settings can be found here: http://www.donkz.nl/files/rdpsettings.html ).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I attempted this, but the link actually leads to another webpage that redirects and closes immediately; probably it's built in a way such that the RDP file isn't saveable, for security reasons.